conditions for a cubic function to be quasiconvex
Under what conditions a cubic function $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ can be considered quasiconcave or quasiconvex. Specifically, I am interested in finding conditions on the coefficients

,

,

that make the function either quasiconvex or quasiconcave.
I have considered the following:

Definition of a quasiconvex function: a function is quasiconvex if, for every $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R},  $the set $\{x \mid f(x)\leq\alpha\}$ is convex
Condition for a quasiconvex function: Suppose $f:$ $R^{n} \to R$  is differentiable,then $f$ is quasiconvex if and only if dom$f$  is convex and for all $x,y\in $ dom$f$,$$ f(y)\leq f(x) \implies \nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x) \leq0 $$ I attempted to solve the problem using the definitions above, but it seems quite challenging to compute directly. Is there a more elegant or simpler way to determine the conditions on

,

,

for a cubic function to be quasiconvex or quasiconcave?

Any suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I suppose that you are assuming that $a\ne0$. Am I right?

a,b,c can be taken from every real number and the problem is to  discuss under what conditions this function is quasiconcave or quasiconvex.

Oh,if a=0, the quadratic function must be quasiconvex.

But if $a=0$ you will not have a cubic anymore, right?!

Yes,  you can suppose a>0.You're right!

If $a=0$ it's trivial, so I'll assume $a\neq 0$.
If $a>0$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, so the sets $\{f\leq \alpha\}$ have the form $(-\infty,e]$ for some $e\in \mathbb R$ (the convex sets of $\mathbb R$ are (possibly infinite) intervals).
But this is equivalent to require that $f$ is non-decreasing (why?), which is equivalent to ask that $f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, which is equivalent to $\Delta=4b^2-12ac\leq 0\iff b^2\leq 3ac$.
The case $a<0$ is analogous and leads to the same inequality.
